# Repository Pattern: SaveOrUpdate() in Entity Framework and L2S

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

[These](http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/Entity-Framework-Four-Part-Three-Repository-Pattern) web articles uses separate Save() and Update() methods for saving and updating an entity.

How can I write a SaveOrUpdate() method in Entity Framework with the help of ObjectContext and in Linq-To-SQL with the help of DataContext?

That is, how can I write a single method that shall do both save and update job?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the Unit of Work pattern - [Angry.Net Developer](http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2009/04/entity-framework-patterns-unit-of-work.html), [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)